# Finding memory leaks while running iPhone unit tests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I know how to do Unit Test on iPhone - the logic tests which run during build phase of the "iPhone Unit Test Bundle".

I know how to detect memory leaks using instruments - in XCode, Menu->Run->run with perf tools->Leaks.

How do I do both? I want to run the unit tests and detect memory leaks in them. If I try to simply select unit-test bundle as target and then "Menu->Run->run with perf tools->Leaks" I get the app loading in simulator but the unit test is not run.

The best I could come up with is include the same unit-test files into my real app target and simply invoke them all from the app itself at runtime. Any better ideas?

Comment: The only way how I was able to find leaks using unit tests - when I learned that some of my `dealloc` methods were not called - you can see that from code coverage, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to check for leaks because they're started up and torn down independently. If you're trying to debug a leak by running the unit tests and seeing if they leak, you're probably better off using something like the clang static analyzer in Xcode 3.2